# Problems caching images with php

Tags: php, google-chrome, caching, header, http-headers

I have two websites one for the visitors and one for the content. On the second one, I'm trying to cache the images because when you go to a certain url the same thing is always going to be there. I cannot figure out how to make my browser (Chrome) cache the images. This is what I'm getting for the responses headers:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=1401497895
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Fri, 31 May 2013 00:58:15 GMT
Expires:Sat, 31 May 2014 00:58:15 +0000
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:public
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2
```

and here is my php setting the headers:

```
header('Expires:Sat, 31 May 2014 00:58:15 +0000');
header('Cache-Control:public, max-age=1401497895');
header('Pragma:public');
```

what am I doing wrong?? I want to minimize the image load time.

Also, I'm accessing them from a CNAME if that matters, although i'm having the same problems with the normal domain.

Answer (score 0):

Why you set max-age so high?
You are trying to set it to nearly 50 years!

This should work but i never tried it with such a high max-age.